# In Org-mode how to call code block to evaluate from other org file?

Tags: emacs, org-mode, spacemacs

Interesting in [OrgMode](http://orgmode.org/manual/) version 9+

Is there a way to reference and evaluate *code block* from **other** org file and to use it's result in main code block in current org file?

Or maybe just to include code block from **other** org file to current code block to compose last one as

```
#+BEGIN_SRS lang :noweb yes
<<reusable-part1>>
<<current-buffer-specific-part>>
<<reusable-part2>>
#+END_SRS
```

and be possible to C-c C-c it.

Answer (score 10):

I think that [Library of Babel](http://orgmode.org/manual/Library-of-Babel.html#Library-of-Babel) is the best way to reuse code across org-mode files.

> For any user to add code to the library, first save the code in
>   regular ‘src’ code blocks of an Org file, and then load the Org file
>   with org-babel-lob-ingest, which is bound to C-c C-v i

To be more explicit, lets say that you have a simple code like this one:

```
#+NAME: simpleShExample
#+BEGIN_SRC sh :var x="default X" :var y="default Y" :export none
  echo "Var: $x, $y"
#+END_SRC
```

This code can be reused with:

```
#+CALL: simpleShExample(y="My y")
```

which prints:

```
Var: default X, My y
```

Now if you save your code in an org file, for instance `simpleShExample.org`
then you can reuse it in any other org files by loading it with this lisp command:

```
(org-babel-lob-ingest "path/to/simpleShExample.org")
```

Note that you can do that once in your emacs init file.

You can check the list of all the source code blocks you have ingested by inspecting the org-babel-library-of-babel variable.

Comment: Well, seems that's not the best, but the ONLY way to reuse code blocks for evaluation :( It's pity that there is no modular way to plugin other files with code blocks

Comment: I am quite happy with the solution I posted, however maybe that we have not the same requirements. Did you try playing with #+INCLUDE ? http://orgmode.org/manual/Include-files.html to directly include your code blocks?

Comment: Yep. #+INCLUDE is ok for tangling, but not working with live-blocks. Also I cannot make #+SETUPFILE works as well in C-c C-c context.

Comment: My idea is to replace [Project Jupyter](http://jupyter.org/) with Org-mode. And to plugin diffent org files with code blocks on-demand as libs

Comment: @DimaFomin ok, I understand the motivation :) and I have also ruminated  about that. However, my current approach is to doc with org mode but to only provide links to the relevant files: your jupyter notebooks  in your case (my C++ code and Mathematica scripts in my cases). The reason why I finally do that is that I realized that If I use org-mode to store code source I lose all the natives tools: completion for C++ code, editor & graphics output for Mathematica... etc.

Answer (score 8):

The following works for me:  Put this in file `one.org`:

```
#+name: the-content
#+begin_src emacs-lisp
(print "hello")
#+end_src

#+name: the-wrapper
#+begin_src org :noweb yes
<<the-content>>
#+end_src
```

and this in file `two.org`:

```
#+begin_src emacs-lisp :noweb yes
<<one.org:the-wrapper()>>
#+end_src
```

executing this block responses `"hello"`.  C-c C-v C-v confirms that the source from `the-content` ends up in the source block.

This solution utilizes that

- noweb blocks can call src-blocks
- org-babel calls can call from other files
- `org` src-blocks respond to a call with their content

Therefore `org` src-blocks can be forwarded over files.  I use a wrap-org-block (`the-wrapper`) that I have the actual language I'm interested in available in the original src-block (`the-content`).

This solution might cause trouble, when elements of the original src-block are interpreted as org-code in the wrapper-block!